# Pokemon Y Cartridge Save Transferred to a Digital Version

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I lost my Pokemon Y cartridge recently (I'm really sad) I wanted to know if I actually need the physical copy of the cartridge to transfer the save to the digital version? It makes sense that you do but just wanted to confirm it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need the game cartridge to transfer the save to the digital version.
The game progress is saved on the cartridge itself, so your 3DS without the game cartridge has no recollection of your game progress.